# Strapi: GraphQL mutation without authentication

Tags: javascript, graphql, strapi

I program simple e-shop based on Strapi. I need to open my custom "order" mutation to public without any JWT token but I can't figure out how. Is it possible to do that in Strapi? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Strapi v4 you can do it like this:

1. Go to "Settings";
2. Open "Roles";
3. Click on the "Public" role;
4. Expand the desired model in the "Permissions" section;
5. Specify which endpoints you want to give rights.

In your case it is "create".

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, I needed set this for my own create mutation with custom code and default create mutation left with protection. However, I've already solved this issue. Set `resolverOf: "application::order.order._create"` on my custom mutation and then add entry for `_create` action for public role to `users-permissions_permission` collection in DB where I set `enabled: true`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/graphql.html#extending-the-schema:

resolversConfig has a property called `auth` which is like:

> auth: false to fully bypass the authorization system and allow all requests

So for example you need to specify your mutation name:

```
  resolversConfig: {
    'Mutation.updateAddress': {
      auth: false,
    },
  },
```

Otherwise just override your resolver